# How to create Multidimensional Key Value array/slice in GoLang

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array, go-gin

I have a `PHP` script in which i'hv created some array formats (data structures) which i want to convert the same array structure using `Golang`.

Below is the array structure of my PHP script

```
   $response['spf']['current_value']  = $spfValue; // this will  be the array of strings
   $response['spf']['required_value'] = "v=spf1 a include:32782.pppp.com ~all";            
   $response['spf']['is_verified']    = $isValidSpf; //this will be int
   $response['spf']['spf_matched']    = $isMatched;  //this will be int
   print_r($response);
```

The outut of above script will be `Array` of key named SPF

`[spf] => Array
    (
        [current_value] => Array
            (
                [0] => v=spf1 a -all,
            )
        [required_value] => v=spf1 a  include:32782.pppp.com ~all
        [is_verified] => 0
        [spf_matched] => 0
    )`

As i am a new in `golang` , Need some golang code which will return same output as per `PHP` script

Comment: Hi sid, what is  exact requirement ? can you explain bit more ?

Comment: Hi Ashish, i am using Golang's GIN framework for development of REST API's. In which i am facing the problem in making the associative array. For a reference  i have mentioned my PHP code which i want to convert in go format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope below code will help you out. Make struct according to your JSON.

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)   

type Resp struct {
    Spf Param `json:"spf"`
}   

type Param struct {
    Is_verified    int            `json:"is_verified"`
    Spf_matched    int            `json:"spf_matched"`
    Required_value string         `json:"required_value"`
    Current_value  map[int]string `json:"current_value"`
}   

func main() {

    str := make(map[int]string)

    str[0] = "v=spf1 a -all,"
    resp := Resp{Spf: Param{Is_verified: 0, Spf_matched: 0, Required_value: "v=spf1 a  include:32782.pppp.com ~all", Current_value: str}}
    js, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
    fmt.Printf("%s", js) 
}
```